# Can't access top level python package from sub packages

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, python-packaging

I have a directory structure like below:

```
chatbot/
    __init__.py
    utils/
    __init__.py
    parser.py
    nlu/
        __init__.py
        training/
                __init__.py
                module.py
```

I want to access `parser.py` from `module.py`.
I tried using this line from `module.py`:

```
from chatbot.utils import parser
```

And I got this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chatbot'
```

Any pointers to what I am doing wrong?
I am using `python3` and trying to run the script as `python3 nlu/training/module.py`.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: My recommendation would be to change to the directory where the _top-level_ modules and packages are (I guess `cd path/to/chatbot/..` in your case) and then call your _executable module_ using the `python -m` form (I guess `path/to/pythonX.Y -m chatbot.nlu.training.module` in your case).

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/470982/how-to-add-a-python-module-to-syspath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the right way of solving such problems is:

- figure out what your *top-level* packages and modules are and in what directory they are
- change to that directory
- make all your imports absolute, i.e. always start with a top-level module or package (instead of things like `from . import blah`)
- use the *executable module* (`python -m`) way of running your code, for example `path/to/pythonX.Y -m top_level_package.executable_module` (instead of `path/to/pythonX.Y top_level_package/executable_module.py`)

In case the *top-level* modules or packages are not all in the same directory:

- Either work on packaging your libraries or applications correctly and install them in the *site packages* (eventually as *editable*, also known as *develop* mode).
- Or, as a last resort, collect the other directories containing the *top-level* packages and modules in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable like the following:

  - `PYTHONPATH=path/to/alpha:path/to/bravo path/to/pythonX.Y -m top_level_package.executable_module`

Comment: Some good points here. I tried with PYTHONPATH and it worked for me.
I am accepting this as the correct solution to my question.

Comment: I hope you tried the other recommendations first. As I said, I believe modifying `PYTHONPATH` should be a last resort solution, or at best it can only be a temporary solution.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve the issue by adding the parent directory of `chatbot` package to `sys.path`.

Say if chatbot python package is in `/home/my_project/chatbot/`, I added a statement like:

> sys.path.append('/home/my_project') in module.py

This made all top-level python packages visible to all lower-level python packages.

Comment: mutating `sys.path` is a bad idea. if it works it works, but a more stable solution would be to either use relative imports instead of absolute ones (`from .. import parser`) or stick to absolute imports but [dev-install](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs) the package to make absolute imports work.

Comment: I'd agree with @Arne. I believe modifying `sys.path` is _rarely_ a good idea.